# Drools rules are not getting fired from remote maven

Tags: java, jboss, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I am using drools workbench 6.4.0 Final and defined 2 Guided decision tables.

I need to execute these remote rules from java application.

i am able to print all the rules but rules are not getting fired.

Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://ip:8080/kie-drools-wb/maven2wb/demo/NewTest/LATEST/NewTest-LATEST.jar";
    ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl( "demo", "NewTest", "LATEST" );
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
    KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);
    KieBase kbase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    System.out.println(kbase.getKiePackage("demo.newtest").getRules());
    KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
    Person details = new Person();   
    details.setAge(20);
    kSession.insert(details);
    System.out.println(kSession.getFactCount());
    System.out.println("Fired rules: " + kSession.fireAllRules());
```

It is giving Number of fired rules count as 0.

Can anyone please help me where i am going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it first locally, does it work ?